# jquery checkbox become checked/unchecked one time, if I try again it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JPPmA/)

Here is the Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#main_chk').click(function(){    

            if(this.checked)
            {
                $(".chks").attr('checked', true);
            }
            else
            {
                $(".chks").removeAttr('checked');                                           
            }

        })
})
```

It works for the very first time (you have to click on the first check box) it will toggle the checkboxes, but if you try again,it doesn't works

Comment: Place your code here for future reference who has the same problem and then add a link to fiddle

Comment: Your HTML has duplicated `id`s. The `id` attribute must be unique. Please fix your HTML markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main_chk').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".chks").prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(".chks").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you can simplify it as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main_chk').change(function () {
        $(".chks").prop('checked', this.checked);
    })
})
```

[See a live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tZeqm/)

**Note:** The `id` attribute must be unique, please fix your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/6bKyq/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main_chk').click(function(){    
        $(".chks").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
$('#main_chk').mousedown(function() {
 if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).trigger("change");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first..your html is invalid since you have more than one id with a same name... ID should always be unique.. change all your id to class..

secondly you can use prop();

```
 $('#main_chk').click(function(){   

    if(this.checked)
    {
      $(".chks").prop('checked', true);
    }
    else
    {
       $(".chks").prop('checked',false);                                            
    }


 })
```